# How to generate code map in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How can I generate a code map in visual studio, can generate class diagram but where is the option for code map ?

Comment: have you tried extension named ... "Code Map" ?

Comment: how would i do that sir ?

Comment: forget it, that's not what you seems to want. See DaveShaw's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have installed Update 1 for VS2012, and be using Professional, Premium or Ultimate editions if Visual Studio.

Taken from this source [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/02/07/visual-studio-2012-update-1-understanding-code-map.aspx):

---

Before we get started you need to be aware of the requirements for Code Map.  Below are the requirements to leverage this feature:

- Visual Studio 2012.1 and one of these editions:

  - Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate to create code maps from the code editor or from Solution Explorer.
  - Visual Studio 2012 Premium or Visual Studio 2012 Professional to open code maps, make limited edits, and navigate code.
- A solution with Visual C# .NET or Visual Basic .NET code

Note: Before you share maps with others who use Premium or Professional, make sure that all the items on the map are visible, such as hidden items, expanded groups, and cross-group links.

Comment: by updating i will get codemap automatically ? i want to use it on a project

Comment: menu `Help` > `About Microsoft Visual Studio`, then read `Version`